# Object must implement IConvertible error when passing an array to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.
>    Line 225: SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

SQL Server type definition:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetDictionaryWords2]
    @categories AS dbo.IdList READONLY
AS
select ... 
from ...
where [category] in (select id from @categories)
```

ASP.Net:

```
public static DictionaryWord[] GetDictionaryWords2(int[] categories)
{
                cmd.CommandText = "GetDictionaryWords2";
                var categoriesParams = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categories", categories);
                categoriesParams.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                categoriesParams.TypeName = "dbo.IdList";
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to pass it as datatable and not as array

Comment: Is there a way to pass it as array? @Rahul

Comment: AFAIK the only provider that can take an array value in a parameter is Npgsql, which relates to the fact that PostgreSQL supports array datatypes directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass it as `DataTable` and not as array. From your posted code, you can convert the passed array to datatable and use that like

```
public static DictionaryWord[] GetDictionaryWords2(int[] categories)
{
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            categories.ToList().ForEach(dr => { DataRow d = dt.NewRow(); d[dc] = dr; dt.Rows.Add(d); });
                cmd.CommandText = "GetDictionaryWords2";
                var categoriesParams = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categories", dt);
                categoriesParams.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                categoriesParams.TypeName = "dbo.IdList";
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```